# Why are tests failing in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I am studying the book "Agile Web Development with Rails 4". In it, at one moment associated with testing, it gives two errors

```
Error:
ProductsControllerTest#test_should_update_product:
ArgumentError: unknown keywords: :id, :product
    test/controllers/products_controller_test.rb:42:in `block in <class:ProductsControllerTest>'

Error:
ProductsControllerTest#test_should_create_product:
ArgumentError: unknown keyword: :product
    test/controllers/products_controller_test.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in <class:ProductsControllerTest>'
    test/controllers/products_controller_test.rb:25:in `block in <class:ProductsControllerTest>'
```

In the same place, the author indicates how to fix them: in the 'setup do' add

```
@update = {
title: 'Lorem Ipsum',
description: 'Wibbles are fun!',
image_url: 'lorem.jpg',
price: 19.95
}
```

In 'should_create_product' replace

```
post products_url, params: { product: { description: @product.description, image_url: @product.image_url, price: @product.price, title: @product.title } }
```

with

```
post :create, product: @update
```

And in 'should_update_product' replace

```
patch product_url(@product), params: { product: { description: @product.description, image_url: @product.image_url, price: @product.price, title: @product.title } }
```

with

```
patch :update, id: @product, product: @update
```

However, after these fixes, the tests continue to give the same errors. How to fix it?

EDITED:
I tried to replace with

```
post :create, params: { product: @update }
```

and

```
patch :update, params: { id: @product, product: @update }
```

Now it gives to me another errors:

```
Error:
ProductsControllerTest#test_should_create_product:
URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): "http://www.example.com:80create"
    test/controllers/products_controller_test.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in <class:ProductsControllerTest>'
    test/controllers/products_controller_test.rb:25:in `block in <class:ProductsControllerTest>'

Error:
ProductsControllerTest#test_should_update_product:
URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): "http://www.example.com:80update"
    test/controllers/products_controller_test.rb:42:in `block in <class:ProductsControllerTest>'
```

Comment: On what rails version are you on? Those errors are from R5 and up, and your book is for R4.  `patch :update, params: { id: @product, product: @update }` should fix in R5.

Comment: My rails version is 6.1.4.1. I replaced as you say, now it gives to me another errors

Comment: `patch "/update", params: { id: @product, product: @update }`

Comment: `Error:
ProductsControllerTest#test_should_create_product:
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [POST] "/create"
    test/controllers/products_controller_test.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in <class:ProductsControllerTest>'
    test/controllers/products_controller_test.rb:25:in `block in <class:ProductsControllerTest>'`


`Error:
ProductsControllerTest#test_should_update_product:
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [PATCH] "/update"
    test/controllers/products_controller_test.rb:42:in `block in <class:ProductsControllerTest>'`

Comment: The path in your url seems to be incorrect http://www.example.com:80create. It probably should be something like this: http://www.example.com:80/products/create. And http://www.example.com:80update http://www.example.com:80/products/update.

Comment: @Smek no. The path needs to start with a slash and should be `/products` and `/products/:id`. You never use `create`, `update` or `destroy` in the path in Rails unless you want to come off as a complete tool.

Comment: @max, that is what your log is telling me. URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): "http://www.example.com:80update" and URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): "http://www.example.com:80create". Do you see any slashes there? I don't.

Comment: @smek what I mean is that you need to pass an actual path and not a symbol like you would in a controller test. Using `"/create"` is just bad advice as it not idiomatically correct.

Comment: @max, I did not say you should write a string in your test. I said path in the url that is being generated is incorrect. I think this is why there is an URI::InvalidURIError raised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing up two different kinds of tests.

The first is functional controller tests in the form of `ActionController::TestCase` which you probably have in your book. These are tests that create a mocked request object and pass it to an instance of the controller. The use of these is greatly discouraged outside of legacy apps since they tend to let tons of bugs through. In functional tests you would write `post :create, params: { product: { ... }}` because you are actually calling the create method on the controller instance.

The second is integration tests in the form of `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest` where you send actual HTTP requests to your Rails application. This is the modern approach and it's just as fast as functional tests in modern versions of Rails which was not the case when the book was written.

In an integration test you pass a path or url:

`post  '/products', params: { product: ... }`

A second issue is the mandatory separation the of keyword parameters that was introduced in Rails 5.

In previous versions of Rails you could call:

```
get '/foo', bar: 1, baz: 2
```

And Rails would treat any unknown keys (not params, headers, format, etc) as parameters which was the source of many bugs. In Rails 5+ you explicitly need to pass parameters in the params option.

```
get '/foo', params: { bar: 1, baz: 2 }
```

I would suggest you complement the book with some more modern sources or get a newer edition as quite a lot has changed since Rails 4 and following a book that old in Rails 6 is going to be painful.